# Querystring of internal rewrite shows up in redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using following `htaccess`

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user/index.php?usr=$1
```

The First three lines redirects non www url to www for my website..

The other line redirects for canonical purpose e.g. `www.mysite.com/user/index.php?usr=JAHAJEE` will become `www.mysite.com/user/JAHAJEE/`.

My problem is after i have added the above redirect for non www to www, the canonical redirected pages show the url parameter (e.g.www.mysite.com/user/JAHAJEE/?usr=JAHAJEE) . Please check http://www.jahajee.com/user/JAHAJEE/ & http://jahajee.com/user/JAHAJEE/

How can I prevent url parameters to be shown in the redirected URL. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[R=301]` will let mod_rewrite know the request should be redirected, but the request will not be redirected instantly. It will evaluate rules until it finds the `[L]` or `[END]` flag (or it hits the end of the file). It now matches the first rule, and tell that when mod_rewrite feels ready, it should redirect. mod_rewrite still hasn't found an `L` or `END` flag yet and still has rules to match. It then will match the second rule and include that in the redirect.

You need to change the flags for the first rule to `[R=301,L]` to make it redirect. The redirected request will invoke this `.htaccess` again and the second rule will be matched if needed. It then will work properly as an internal rewrite again.

Comment: Its still not working. I removed the 301 completely and added [L] after 1st rewrite rule but still it does show url parameter when redirected from non www url

Comment: Clear your cache. Because of the 301 in your original rule the previous rewrite is cached and it will simply skip the first url. That's the reason why you should never test with permanent redirects until everything works as expected.

Comment: You need to clear the browser cache for the site. If you open the network tab of the developer console you should see that it requests the original url from the *server*, and not from cache. The response should be 302 (temporary redirect).

Comment: Awesome ...that does it ...I just tried in other browser and it worked. Thank you . 
Just 1 more question. What I understood about the redirect part is that the browser cached 301 redirect rule so that it does not redirect again ! So whenever testing with 301 redirect happens, I need to clear browser cache too ?? Right ??

Comment: When you test you should always use `[R]` (302: Temporary redirect). When the browser requests page `a` and that returns a 301 status code to load page `b` instead, the browser will load `b`. In the near future, when the user clicks a link to `a` or puts a link to `a` in the address future in the near future, the browser will not request `a` again from the server, but instead request `b` immedeatelly. If you accidentally test with a 301 redirect, you'll need to clear that cache indeed, so it requests page `a` again.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use 301 or 303 redirect
**301** for permanently
**303** for temporary